# Formal notion of "which indices contain variation" in a set of bitstrings

Tags: combinations, coding-theory, entropy

I am interested in defining a function $f$ that maps a set of length-n bitstrings to a list of n numbers in $[0,1]$. Each number can be interpreted as indicating how much variation there is among those bitstrings, that involves that index. For example:

- $f(\{0,1\})= \langle 1 \rangle$
  (the set contains two elements, so one bit of variation, and there is only one index that it involves)
- $f(\{001, 000\}) = \langle 0,0,1 \rangle $
  (there is one bit of variation, and it only involves the final index)
- $f(\{010, 011, 100, 101\}) = \langle \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, 1 \rangle $
  (there are two bits of variation, and half of it involves the last index)
- $f(\{100, 010, 001, 111\}) = \langle \frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3}\rangle $ (there are two bits of variation, and they involve all of the indices.)

(The sum of outputs will always equal $log_2 m$, where $m$ is the number of bitstrings provided.)

Is there a well-known function that does this, or some terms that I should look up, in order to understand this problem?

Comment: Hello! May you please edit your question with MathJax? A guide to MathJax can be found here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/1098096

Comment: Sure, this should be fixed now

Comment: In your third example, each of the three bits gets $0$ twice and $1$ twice, so it seems like the result should be $\langle1,1,1\rangle$ or $\langle\tfrac13,\tfrac13,\tfrac13\rangle$, with all bits having the same variation.

Comment: Or do you have an (ordered) tuple of bitstrings, rather than an (unordered) set of bitstrings? In that case, your fourth example would lose its symmetry; I would expect the result to be something like $\langle2,3,1\rangle$.

Comment: The reason that I want the third case to output $\langle \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, 1 \rangle$ is that the first two bits only contain one bit of information, because the second bit is always known from the first and vice versa. I don't want to just consider the frequencies of each digit at each index, independently.

Comment: You've chosen examples where we can divide the indexes into groups so that the digit values are independent between groups and symmetric within each group, but it's not clear what your function should do when such a division isn't possible. (I guess that's your question, in a way.) E.g. what should $f(\{001,010,100,110\})$ be?

Comment: @Karl: Yes, I agree that's roughly the question. One could argue that $f(\{001,010,100,110\})=\langle 1,1,0\rangle$ on the basis that we consider each digit from left to right, and we only need the first two digits to divide the set into its four elements. The same logic would of course imply for my fourth example that $f(\{100,010,001,111\})=\langle 1,1,0\rangle$, however. So maybe to formalise this idea, it will be natural to dispense with the idea of treating the digits symmetrically.